# Bash script run as cron job @reboot to set Nvidia settings does not set values?

Tags: command-line, nvidia, bash, scripts, cron

I have a bash script

```
#!/bin/bash

# Enable nvidia-smi settings so they are persistent the whole time the system is on.
nvidia-smi -pm 1

# Define the various overclocking settings (powerLimit in watts)
powerLimit="100"
coreOffset="150"
memoryOffset="1000"
targetFanSpeed="40"

TOTAL_GPU=5
GPU_INDEX=0
while [  $GPU_INDEX -lt $TOTAL_GPU ]; do
    nvidia-smi -i $GPU_INDEX -pl $powerLimit
    nvidia-settings -a [gpu:$GPU_INDEX]/GpuPowerMizerMode=1
    nvidia-settings -a [gpu:$GPU_INDEX]/GPUMemoryTransferRateOffset[3]=$memoryOffset
    nvidia-settings -a [gpu:$GPU_INDEX]/GPUGraphicsClockOffset[3]=$coreOffset
    nvidia-settings -a [gpu:$GPU_INDEX]/GPUFanControlState=1
    nvidia-settings -a [fan:$GPU_INDEX]/GPUTargetFanSpeed=$targetFanSpeed
    let GPU_INDEX=GPU_INDEX+1 
done
```

To set an overclock on the GPUs installed in my system. I am trying to run this script on startup to automate the system on a reboot. To do so I have edited my root crontab with the entries

```
0 0 * * * reboot -h now
@reboot bash /home/rig0/Documents/startup/1060OC.sh > /home/rig0/Documents/startup/1060OC.log
```

I am piping the output of the bash script into a log file to make sure that each setting is successful. My first, minor problem, is that some of the text that is output when I run the bash script form a terminal, is not caught in this file

For instance the log output from the cron job is (for just one GPU)

```
Enabled persistence mode for GPU 00000000:07:00.0.
...
Power limit for GPU 00000000:07:00.0 was set to 100.00 W from 150.00 W.
All done.
```

But when ran in the console the text reads (for just one GPU)

```
Power limit for GPU 00000000:07:00.0 was set to 100.00 W from 100.00 W.
All done.
  Attribute 'GPUPowerMizerMode' (rig0-System-Product-Name:0[gpu:4]) assigned
  value 1.
  Attribute 'GPUMemoryTransferRateOffset' (rig0-System-Product-Name:0[gpu:4])
  assigned value 1000.
  Attribute 'GPUGraphicsClockOffset' (rig0-System-Product-Name:0[gpu:4])
  assigned value 150.
  Attribute 'GPUFanControlState' (rig0-System-Product-Name:0[gpu:4]) assigned
  value 1.
  Attribute 'GPUTargetFanSpeed' (rig0-System-Product-Name:0[fan:4]) assigned
  value 40.
```

**Why do I not see the "extra" text when the output is piped to the log file in the cron job?**

I assume I need to do something like [this U&L answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/52332/58449) and add the redirect `2>&1`. Which from earlier reading I think means to pipe `std.err` to `std.out` for the command?.

---

Though... I think the real issue, and the main question of this post is, none of the settings from the cron job bash script are actually set (I need to check, I think the wattage is set, but I forget).

**Are these settings not actually set because the cron job runs before the Nvidia X server starts up?**

Basically the calls to `nvidia-settings ...` don't take effect because the X server using the `nvidia` driver is not yet running at the time the cron job is ran?

---

**Is there a way I could check, and wait, for the X server to be running in my bash script?** This would allow the cron job to wait until the settings it tries to effect are available.

Maybe I can add the proposed solution from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46778213/2985796) ?

---

**EDIT:** I found and [old RedHat archive](https://www.redhat.com/archives/redhat-install-list/2009-February/msg00006.html) that gave me a way to allow the bash script to wait for the X server to startup

```
# Wait for the X server to startup
echo "Waiting for the X server to startup..."
XON=""
while [ "$XON" == "" ]; do
    /bin/sleep 5
    echo "    Checking for X server."
    XON=$(ps ax | grep -v grep | grep -i xorg)
    echo "    Result:[$XON]"
done
echo "X server started. Setting overclock settings..."
```

Which does seem to wait for the X server to start up based on the log file output

```
Waiting for the X server to startup...
    Checking for X server.
    Result:[  978 tty7     Rs+    0:01 /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg -core :0 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch]
X server started. Setting overclock settings...
Enabled persistence mode for GPU 00000000:01:00.0.
```

Though the same issues persist. The settings do not take hold and the output I would expect from the settings commands, are not present in the log.

**Do I need to wait for `nvidia`-something to start maybe..?**

---

**EDIT2:** First, I've moved the same cron command into my `rc.local` because it seems as a more correct solution.

Next, I've redirected the output `2>&1` and found the error message

```
Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

ERROR: The control display is undefined; please run `nvidia-settings
       --help` for usage information.
```

Which seems to be [a common problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/925368/cannot-run-nvidia-settings/937204) on headless systems trying to run the `nvidia-settings` command, and seems to be solved with `export DISPLAY:0`. Though, given that I have a head'ed system, I am not sure if this is the correct solution, or exactly the effects of `export DISPLAY:0`, especially on a head'ed system.

Doing some research...

Comment: Yes you probably need to add `2>&1` to capture stderr as well as stdout - you should then be able to see errors in the logfile which **may** give a clue as to what's not working. (Often it's things like executables not being in cron's default path - where is `nvidia-smi` located, for example?)

Comment: Ohhh, hmm, `nvidia-smi` should be in cron's path because the power limits are confirmed to be set. But, `nvidia-settings` probably isn't then. I'll add `2>&1` to capture and see if that is indeed the issue and use absolute paths to `nvidia-settings` then. // I just tried to run the same commad from the cron in `rc.local` with the same results. Though, I think `rc.local` should see `nvidia-settings` given when it runs..? But I'm too novice to know.

Comment: @steeldriver I've made another edit. But after some research, it might be a bit specific of an issue. Basically the same issue is encountered on headless systems trying to run `nvidia-settings`, and is subsequently solved by `export DISPLAY:0`. Though, I dont exactly understand what this means, and seeing as I have a head'ed system, I think it would be a mistake to blinldy copypasta that.

Comment: Setting `DISPLAY=:0` is just a way to tell nvidia-settings which X display to connect to - I don't think any harm can come from it.